# Reasoning questions on Solubility

Tags: solubility, solutions

Why is solute dissolved faster in amorphous state and at high temperature?

I don't have any idea about the dissolving of a solute in amorphous state but for higher temperature it might be because the solution is more unaaturated; but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Things at higher temperature dissolve faster because the molecules move faster with heat, increasing the speed of the reaction. Things in an amorphous state have their molecules arranged randomly, their structure is less stable giving them greater solubility than crystalline structures.